# Cobol XML - Remove empty tags

Tags: xml, cobol

I want to generate XML statement without empty tags in cobol. My current output doesnt remove the parent tag if child value is empty.
below is my structure.

```
    01 GrpHdr.
      02 A1.
      03 MsgId                         PIC X(50) VALUE SPACES.
      03 Test3.
        05 Test31.
          07 Test32                    PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
        05 Test4.
          07 Test5.
            09 Test6.
              11 Test7                 PIC X(10) VALUE SPACES.
    MAIN-PARA.
    
            MOVE 'MESSAGE ID'          TO MsgId.
            MOVE SPACES                TO Test32.
            MOVE 'TEST7'               TO Test7.
    
            INITIALIZE OUTPUT-XML.
    
                XML GENERATE OUTPUT-XML from Grphdr
SUPPRESS Test31 EVERY NONUMERIC ELEMENT WHEN SPACES
                  ON EXCEPTION
                     DISPLAY 'GENERATE XML Error-Header'
                  NOT ON EXCEPTION
                     CONTINUE
            END-XML
            XML PARSE OUTPUT-XML PROCESSING PROCEDURE 1-XML-PARSE-FORM.

    MAIN-EXIT.
        EXIT.

         1-XML-PARSE-FORM SECTION.
         *----------------------*
    
          EVALUATE XML-EVENT
            WHEN 'START-OF-ELEMENT'
            IF ELEMENT NOT = SPACE
              IF DEPTH > 1
                MOVE SPACES TO XML-REC
                STRING INDENT(1:2 * DEPTH - 2) DELIMITED BY SIZE
                       BUFFER(1:POSD - 1)      DELIMITED BY SIZE
                        INTO XML-REC
                MOVE SPACES  TO BUFFER
              WRITE XML-REC  
    
            ELSE
              MOVE BUFFER(1:POSD - 1) TO XML-REC
              MOVE SPACES   TO BUFFER
              IF XML-REC NOT = SPACES AND LOW-VALUES
                 WRITE XML-REC 
              END-IF
            END-IF
          END-IF
         MOVE XML-TEXT TO ELEMENT
         ADD 1 TO DEPTH
         MOVE 1 TO POSE
         STRING '<' XML-TEXT '>' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO BUFFER
             WITH POINTER POSE
         MOVE POSE TO POSD
       WHEN 'CONTENT-CHARACTERS'
         MOVE 'N' TO WS-VALUE-SPACES
         STRING XML-TEXT DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO BUFFER
             WITH POINTER POSD
         IF XML-TEXT = SPACES
            MOVE 'Y'   TO WS-VALUE-SPACES
            MOVE SPACES  TO XML-REC
         END-IF
       WHEN 'END-OF-ELEMENT'
         IF WS-VALUE-SPACES NOT = 'Y'
         STRING '</' XML-TEXT '>' DELIMITED BY SIZE INTO BUFFER
             WITH POINTER POSD
           IF DEPTH > 1
             MOVE SPACES TO XML-REC
             STRING INDENT(1:2 * DEPTH - 2) DELIMITED BY SIZE
                       BUFFER(1:POSD - 1)   DELIMITED BY SIZE
                                      INTO XML-REC
             WRITE XML-REC
           ELSE
                MOVE BUFFER(1:POSD - 1) TO XML-REC
                WRITE XML-REC
             END-IF
           END-IF
           SUBTRACT 1 FROM DEPTH
           MOVE 1 TO POSD
           MOVE SPACE TO ELEMENT
           MOVE SPACE TO BUFFER
         WHEN OTHER
           CONTINUE
     END-EVALUATE.

 1-EXIT.
     EXIT.
```

If tag TEST32 is empty and tag Test7 is non empty, i want the output like below,

```
<GrpHdr>
<A1>
    <MsgId>MESSAGE ID</MsgId>
    <Test3>
        <Test4>
            <Test5>
                <Test6>
                    <Test7>TEST7</Test7>
                </Test6>
            </Test5>
        </Test4>
    </Test3>
</A1>
</GrpHdr>
```

Could you please help me to achieve this.

My current output doesnt remove the parent tag if child value is empty.

```
<GrpHdr>
    <A1>
        <MsgId>MESSAGE ID</MsgId>
        <Test3>
            <TEST31></TEST31>
            <Test4>
                <Test5>
                    <Test6>
                        <Test7>TEST7</Test7>
                    </Test6>
                </Test5>
            </Test4>
        </Test3>
    </A1>
    </GrpHdr>
```

Comment: That's undertandable. Please check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more about how this site works - and then present the code you're currently using and what you achieve with it - not only the "I want that result".

Comment: Why exactly do you care? It doesn't make any difference to any correctly written XML processor.

Comment: I have a requirement to not populate few tags based on business conditions. For few scenarios, I have to populate values (non-empty) to tag TEST32.

Comment: Have you tried using the SUPPRESS phrase of the XML GENERATE statement?

Comment: oh no.. Havent tried SUPPRESS option. Could you please give me a sample..

Answer (score 2):

Try using the SUPPRESS phrase of the [XML GENERATE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=statements-xml-generate-statement).

```
        XML GENERATE OUTPUT-XML from Grphdr
              SUPPRESS TEST31 WHEN SPACES
              ON EXCEPTION
                 DISPLAY 'GENERATE XML Error-Header'
              NOT ON EXCEPTION
                 CONTINUE
        END-XML
```

Comment: Getting compilation error -->  IGYPA3297-E   "SUPPRESS identifier "TEST31 (GROUP)" was not an elementary data item. The "SUPPRESS" phrase was discarded.

Comment: Code compiled after using 'EVERY NONUMERIC ELEMENT WHEN SPACES' .

If I populate non empty value to tag 'TEST32' and populate SPACES to tag 'TEST7', im getting output like below

<GrpHdr><A1><MsgId>MESSAGE ID</MsgId></A1></GrpHdr>

Not displaying the tag TEST32 , TEST31, TEST3